# Как выровнять текст кнопки по вертикали?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qss, qpushbutton

Недавно начал изучать *PyQt* и *Qt Designer* в частности, но столкнулся с проблемой.

Я хочу создать кнопку со знаком **`+`** по середине.

Для этого я создал `QPushButton` и добавил на нее текст **`+`**. 
Как понятно из картинки ниже, текст смещен к низу кнопки.

Как можно его расположить в середине?

[image: QPushButton с текстом "+"б смещенным вниз от центра]

---

Что я пробовал:

```html
vertical-align: center; - эффекта нет
text-align: center;     - выравнивает, но только по горизонтали
margin: 10px;           - желаемого результата тоже не дает (см картинку ниже)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю, что могу решить свою задачу через добавление иконки, но хочу понять, есть ли способ сделать это через текст самой кнопки.

Comment: текст на кнопке и без того по умолчанию выравнивается по центру

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не просто, если вы сильно изменяете размеры `font`.
Расположение текста основано на шрифте "bounding rectangle". В Qt Designer вы такого не сделаете.

Вот вам простой вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton(
            objectName="BlueButton",     
            clicked=lambda: print('Hello'))
        )


StyleSheet = '''
QPushButton { 
    border-image: url(plus.png); 
}
#BlueButton {
    background-color: #2196f3;
    min-width:  100px;
    max-width:  100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
#BlueButton:hover {
    background-color: #64b5f6;
}
#BlueButton:pressed {
    background-color: #bbdefb;
}
'''        
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**plus.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно, Этот подход значительно проще, чем пытаться идеально выровнять текст.

Comment: @КачановАртём пожалуйста.